# Two buttons in one DataTable cell; one is smaller than the othr

Tags: html, button, bootstrap-4

Im working with a DataTable that has a column containing two Bootstrap-styled buttons. For some reason the button on the right is slightly smaller than the left one.

[Image of said problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vk7Nq.png)

Below the code:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block mr-4" style="font-size:20px"> Hoogbouw</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" style="font-size:20px"> Laagbouw</button>
 </div>;
```

Css:

```
.dataTable tbody tr {
  height: 425px; 
}
.btn-group{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
h1{
 text-align: center; 
}
```

Anything wrong?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Answer (score 0):

Need you to provide additional code, what you have appears fine but what does each individual button look like in terms of formatting? Colours don't default to red and green.